# How do you create a pull request for all pushes in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

I am trying to setup a basic group of 3 on bitbucket and trying to understand how I can setup this code reviewing tool to do the following:

```
Every time anyone pushes up a change from local host to the bitbucket repo 
it does not automatically get merged in the bitbucket source

Two other reviews beside myself must approve or +2 the changes
before being merged to source
```

Currently no pull request gets created and every time I make a change and git push. Instead the changes skip review and are merged straight to source and show the commit history

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you commit all of your changes to the `master` branch?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to decide what workflow to follow for your project. There are many different workflows. The one you choose depends entirely on the way your team works together. Atlassian, the company which owns Bit Bucket, has a great guide to help you get started: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows. Almost all work flows use branches in some way. You can create a new branch and commit your work to that branch. When you do this, then you can create a Pull Request from your branch back to the `master` branch.